# Do I have to reset every time that I select a different GPU?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm using Nvidia Prime profiles to switch between my two GPUs (Nvidia and Intel), And since I think that working with my high performance GPU(Nvidia) all the time can harm my system, I would like to change to Nvidia whenever its necessary. When I do that Nvidia prime profile prompt a message saying that you should log out in order to apply the changes, But when I log out and then log in nothing has changed, I have to reset my system whenever I want to select a different GPU. Why the logoff and logon method does not work for me?

Im using Ubuntu 15, With Gnome.